Implementing 'force-static' for Unauthenticated Users Only
I'm facing a challenge with Next.js 14 where I need to conditionally apply (export const dynamic = 'force-static') based on the user's authentication status. My goal is to serve statically generated pages to unauthenticated users to improve load times and SEO, while providing a dynamic experience for authenticated users. I'm currently using NextAuth for the authentication system.
The problem arises because when I use force-static within a page.tsx file, it serves the same static page to both authenticated and unauthenticated users, without differentiation.
How can I configure Next.js to serve static pages only to unauthenticated users and dynamic pages to authenticated ones? Is there a specific setup or strategy within Next.js and NextAuth that facilitates this?
I haven't implemented any specific code to achieve this functionality yet because I'm unsure of the best approach to take with Next.js and NextAuth.
